# can't write the correct syntax for the next query

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 3 entities besides *User* : *Answer, Question* and *Votes_on_Answers* which contains users votes of answers

Answer is associated with Question table by Many-To-One relationship
I need to write query that sums the amount of votes of answer and sort them but I have diffulty with writing the if statement

```
select a.id, a.question_id, a.user_id,
 case
    when sum(voa.vote) = null
        then 0
    else sum(voa.vote)
    end as i
from answer as a left join votes_on_answers as voa on a.id = voa.answer_id 
    where a.question_id = 1
    group by a.id order by i desc;
```

This query returns:

```
id   question_id   i
1    1             3
2    1            -2
3    1            null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could avoid the case .. when and use ifnul()

```
select a.id
, a.question_id
, sum(ifnull(voa.vote,0)) as i
from answer as a 
left join votes_on_answers as voa on a.id = voa.answer_id 
where a.question_id = 1
group by a.id 
order by i desc;
```

or using case

```
select a.id
, a.question_id
, sum(case when voa.vote is null then 0 else voa.vote end)) as i
from answer as a 
left join votes_on_answers as voa on a.id = voa.answer_id 
where a.question_id = 1
group by a.id 
order by i desc;
```

Comment: Perfect! But Is it technically also possible to do it with case statement ? If yes, how it would by look like ?)

Answer (score 0):

You might find that a correlated subquery is simpler and faster . . . and you don't have to worry about `null` values:

```
select a.id, a.question_id, a.user_id,
       (select coalesce(sum(v.votes), 0)
        from votes_on_answers voa 
        where a.id = voa.answer_id 
       ) as i
from answer a
where a.question_id = 1
order by i desc;
```

For performance you want an index on `votes_on_answers(answer_id)`.

Avoiding the outer `group by` is a win from the performance perspective.  When there are no matches in `voa`, the `count(*)` returns `0`.

Comment: but I need to use sum() function, cause vote field in votes_on_answers table can be -1

Comment: @D.Nursultan . . . Then use `sum()` instead.

Comment: then result is exactly the same as above in my question (contains null)